# Which web server should I select during SSL certificate activation if I run a custom Node.js server?

Tags: https, webserver, amazon-ec2

Which web server should I select during SSL certificate activation if I run a custom Node.js server?

I need to know to activate my SSL certificate. There are many options such as:

- Apache
- cPanel
- nginx
- etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that no specific server type is necessary in the case of using a custom Node.js server. You should be able to either leave the server type field blank or, in my case, select "other" as the type.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out and answered your own question. It will help others which is what we try and do here. Thank You!